# How do i figure out on the frontend if the User is logged in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

im currently working on a project and i try to implement a login-system using Json Web Token. My knowledge is basically put together by some tutorials and documentations.
Its basically a MERN Application. The authentication in the backend is working fine until now. My question is how i figure out on the frontend if the user is logged in or not, and based on that i want to display the profile-button instead of the login/register-button. Im aware of the fact that the token has to be stored in a cookie or the localstorage. But i was told that this is quite insecure, since those two storages can be accessed via cross-site-scripting. And now im quite stuck with it. I hope that some experts of you could help me with that. My frontend is a normal form with the "/login" or "/register" action and im using React.js. This is how my backend looks like:

```js
app.post("/register", async (req,res) => {

    //Validation

    const {error} = registerValidation(req.body)

    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

    //Check if user is already in Database

    const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

    if(emailExist) return res.status(400).send("User already registered")

    // Create User 
    try{
        
        const saltRounds = 10;

        var hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds)

        const user = new User({
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            lastname:req.body.lastname,
            gender:req.body.gender,
            birth:req.body.birth,
            street:req.body.street,
            streetnumber:req.body.streetnumber,
            location: req.body.location,
            email:req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword,

        })

        user.save().then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            res.redirect("/registered")
        })
        
    }
    catch{
        res.status(400).send(err)
    }
})

//Login

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {

    // Validation

    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body)
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

    // Check if email exist in DB
    
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send("No user found")
    console.log(user)

    // Password is correct 
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Wrong password")
    
    // Create and assign token
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET)
 
    res.header("auth-token", token).redirect("/main")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware of the fact that the token has to be stored in a cookie or the localstorage.

Those are the obvious places to store it if it needs to persist. (A SPA could get away with keeping it in memory (also vulnerable to XSS)).

> But i was told that this is quite insecure, since those two storages can be accessed via cross-site-scripting.

An HttpOnly cookie wouldn't be accessible to XSS attacks, but XSS could be used to make HTTP requests which include it so that isn't a perfect defence.

Frankly, if you are vulnerable to XSS then you have serious problems. Apply the usual defences against XSS (e.g. user input escaping and a robust CSP) and don't twist yourself up in knots over having data you want to make available to JavaScript without allowing a compromised front end to access it with JavaScript.